# select specific columns to normalize in Pycaret

Tags: python, normalization, pycaret

How to select specific columns, in the Pycaret setup function, to normalization?
I would not like to apply the normalization function to my entire dataframe, just a few columns.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any code, but I'll assume you have access to the dataframe before Pycaret setup function. In that case you can normalize columns before the setup.

```
colsNorm = ['Col1','Col2']
dataframe[colsNorm] = dataframe[colsNorm].apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))
```